# The Jquery Tree Menu and Loading Files in Separate Section

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using JQuery Plugin

https://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-fileTree/demo/ for a jquerytree, which works fine with this code

This is my screen for folders:

http://prntscr.com/l43k90

and this for files

```
<li class="file ext_zip"><a data-name="Files-54-001.pdf" class="filedisplay" data-extention="pdf" rel="c:/Users/Downloads/">Files-54-001.pdf(25137KB)</a></li>  


function showfiles(id) {
    $("#mainfilesarea").removeClass('wordwrap blur');
    $("#mainfilesarea").load('includes/filestypes.cfm?dir='+encodeURIComponent($(id).attr('rel')),'#mainfilesarea');
    if($("#mainfilesarea").html() == '') {
        $("#mainfilesarea").html('Files Selected from the above selected folders will be displayed here').addClass('blur');
    }
}

<a data-name="a.pdf" class="filedisplay" data-extention="pdf" rel="c:/Users/Documents/">a.pdf (406KB)</a>
```

but moving ahead, adding some more piece of code to display the files in a separate panel of the screen using the following, tried to fix some code where complex types of files should be opened in `colorbox` but my call is always hitting the `main.cfm` file

and not loading the complex files in the colorbox, something is really messy

```
$(document).on('click','.filedisplay',function() {
    var dataid = $(this).attr('rel') + $(this).data('name');
    var ext = $(this).data('extention');
    ShowFile(dataid,ext);
});

function ShowFile(strPath,ext){
    if (objHttpFileDataRequest){
        objHttpFileDataRequest.abort();
    }
    objHttpFileDataRequest = $.get(
        "includes/main.cfm",
        {path: encodeURI(strPath)},
        function(strFileData){
            openFile(strFileData,ext);
        }
    );
}
var objHttpFileDataRequest = null;

function openFile(strFileData,ext) {
    var extension = ext;
    switch(extension) {
        case 'xls':
        case 'xlsx':
        case 'pdf':
        case 'csv':
        case 'doc':
        case 'docx':
        $.colorbox({
            href: 'includes/dspcomplexfile.cfm?fileUrl='+strFileData,
            type:'iframe',
            width:'700px;',
            height:'500px;'
        });
        break;     
        default:
        $("#readerArea pre#filecontent").text(strFileData);
    }
};
```

if you ask about `ext` - That is i am getting the `extension` of the file using the `data-extension` attribute

Comment: console log the `ext` in `openFile`, does it log an extension that is not included in any of the `switch`'s cases?

Comment: it outputs the correct extension, i checked that